# what is $this->load->view() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

`$this` is use for current class and `view` is method but what is `load`. Is this a property?

Is this example correct?

```
class super{

    public $property;

    public function superf1()
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
    public function col()
    {
        $this->superf1();
    }

    $this->property->super1();

}
```

Comment: Have a look here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html and here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `load` is a property.
Think of it like this:

```
class Loader {
    public function view() {
        //code...
    }
}

class MyClass {
     private $load;

     public __constructor() {
         $this->load = new Loader();
     }

     public someMethod() {
         $this->load->view();
     }
}
```

This syntax is called chaining.

Comment: very helpful. thank you <?php 
class Loader {
    public function view() {
        echo "hello";
    }
}

class MyClass extends Loader{
     private $load;

     public function __constructor() {
         
     }

     public function someMethod() {
        $this->load = new Loader();
         $this->load->view();
     }
}

$m = new MyClass();
$m->someMethod();
 ?>

Answer (score 2):

Your controller inherits `CI_Controller`. So, if you look in `application/system/core/Controller.php` you'll find something interesting : `$this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');` (l.50 with CI2). So, $this->load refer to the file `application/system/core/Loader.php` which have a function `public function view` (l.418 with CI2)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a class that extends `CI_Controller` (in other words: a controller) the symbol `$this` is the Codeigniter "super object". Which is, more or less, the central object for CI sites and contains (among other things) a list of loaded classes. `load` is one of the classes you'll always find there because it is automatically loaded by the CI system.

Technically, the class creates objects of the type `CI_Loader`. `view()` is just one of the many methods in the `load` class. Other commonly used class methods are `model()`, `library()`, `config()`, `helper()`, and `database()`. There are others.

So, in short, `load` is a class used to load other resources.

Answer (score 0):

`load` is  a class belongs to the loader class
[codeigniter official documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html?highlight=loader%20class)

`view`, `model` and others are `methods`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 8.1
use `return("viewname", $data)`